# WP-Deploy, Capistrano, issues with bundle exec cap production uploads:pull

Tags: php, wordpress, capistrano

I am attempting to fetch the uploads directory on my server, I am using https://github.com/Mixd/wp-deploy as a deployment system.

All other SSH commands work, such as deploy, etc, but this command fails for some reason, here is the trace.

```
Ivans-MacBook-Pro:project ivanristic$ sudo bundle exec cap production uploads:pull --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke uploads:pull (first_time)
** Execute uploads:pull
INFO [46ceea35] Running /usr/bin/env rsync -avzO ec2-user@project.com:/var/www/html/shared/content/uploads/ content/uploads as root@localhost
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rsync exit status: 3072
rsync stdout: Nothing written
rsync stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-45/rsync/io.c(453) [receiver=2.6.9]
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:95:in `exit_status='
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/local.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open3.rb:199:in `popen_run'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open3.rb:93:in `popen3'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/local.rb:63:in `block in _execute'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/local.rb:58:in `tap'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/local.rb:58:in `_execute'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/local.rb:27:in `execute'
/Library/WebServer/Documents/project/lib/capistrano/tasks/content.cap:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Library/WebServer/Documents/project/lib/capistrano/tasks/content.cap:15:in `each'
/Library/WebServer/Documents/project/lib/capistrano/tasks/content.cap:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/local.rb:15:in `instance_exec'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/local.rb:15:in `run'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/dsl.rb:59:in `run_locally'
/Library/WebServer/Documents/project/lib/capistrano/tasks/content.cap:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:15:in `run'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/ivanristic/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => uploads:pull
```

**Deploy.rb:**

```
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.4
lock '3.4.0'

############################################
# Setup WordPress
############################################

set :wp_user, "Ivan" # The admin username
set :wp_email, "somemail" # The admin email address
set :wp_sitename, "some title" # The site title
set :wp_localurl, "http://localhost/project/wordpress" # Your local environment URL

############################################
# Setup project
############################################

set :application, "someappname"
set :repo_url, "git@github.com:Ivan0905/project.git"
set :scm, :git

set :git_strategy, SubmoduleStrategy

############################################
# Setup Capistrano
############################################

set :log_level, :info
set :use_sudo, false

set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  keys: ["/Users/ivanristic/ssh/EC2-key.pem"]
}

set :keep_releases, 5

############################################
# Linked files and directories (symlinks)
############################################

set :linked_files, %w{wp-config.php .htaccess}
set :linked_dirs, %w{content/uploads}
```

**Production.rb**

```
############################################
# Setup Server
############################################

set :stage, :production
set :stage_url, "https://project.com"
server "project.com", user: "ec2-user", roles: %w{web app db}
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/html"

############################################
# Setup Git
############################################

set :branch, "master"

############################################
# Extra Settings
############################################

#specify extra ssh options:

#set :ssh_options, {
#    auth_methods: %w(password),
#    password: 'password',
#    user: 'username',

#set :ssh_options, {
#  forward_agent: true,
#  auth_methods: ["publickey"],
#  keys: ["/Users/ivanristic/ssh/Bill-key.pem"]
#}

#specify a specific temp dir if user is jailed to home
#set :tmp_dir, "/path/to/custom/tmp"
```

The ec2 key is valid, and it works for stuff such as:

```
bundle exec cap production deploy
```

but for some reason it is not working when I attempt to fetch the uploads directory from production.

The uploads dir does exist at, /var/www/html/shared/content/uploads, and it is very populated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm assuming that you know that running such commands as root is bad practice and you have a good reason to do so anyway.

The ssh keys are messed up somehow. The line:

```
rsync stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
```

is pointing this out.

I'm unsure as to why it is trying to run the rsync command as root on localhost. It might be that the ssh key is not installed for the root user.

Try running

```
rsync -avzO ec2-user@project.com:/var/www/html/shared/content/uploads/ content/uploads
```

and see if that sheds light.